# EF problem saving one of several entities

Tags: entity-framework-4

I have the classes Person and Dog.
A dog belongs to one Person and a Person can have different dogs (so one-to-many).

I have a test method that gets 2 persond out of the db. If a person does not exist in the db, I make it. Then I want to save 4 dogs.

This is the test:

```
Person person1= personResourceAccess.GetPersonByName("Person1");
        if(person1==null)
        {
            Person person = new Person()
                            {
                                Name = "Person1"
                            };
            person1= personResourceAccess.CreatePerson(person);
        }
Person person2= personResourceAccess.GetPersonByName("Person2");
            if(person2==null)
            {
                Person person = new Person()
                                {
                                    Name = "Person2"
                                };
                person2= personResourceAccess.CreatePerson(person);
            }
Dog dog1 = new Dog(){name="Dog1", owner = person1};
Dog dog2 = new Dog(){name="Dog2", owner = person1};
Dog dog3 = new Dog(){name="Dog3", owner = person1};
Dog dog4 = new Dog(){name="Dog4", owner = person2};

dog1 = dogResourceAccess.CreateDog(dog1);
dog2 = dogResourceAccess.CreateDog(dog2);
dog3 = dogResourceAccess.CreateDog(dog3 );
dog4 = dogResourceAccess.CreateDog(dog4 );
```

This is the code of the resource access:

```
public Dog CreateDog(Dog dog)
    {
        try
        {
            db.Dogs.AddObject(dog);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return dog;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return null
        }
    }
```

When I save the first dog, all other dogs are created in the db. Why is this and how can I prevent it from happening?
I think it might have something to do with the context but I can't seem to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is correct behavior. `SaveChanges` always save all changes currently tracked by the context. There is no way to avoid it - it is called unit of work. The reason why this happens is assigning owner in initialization of the new dog. Person is already tracked by the context so assigning it to any other entity will immediately start tracking of that entity.

If you want to save changes in sequence you must do it different way:

```
Dog dog1 = new Dog(){name="Dog1"};
dog1 = dogResourceAccess.CreateDog(dog1);
dog1.owner = person1; // Attach the person after you added a new dog.
```